# React update component after loading data

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, redux, google-cloud-firestore

So I have a component that shows categories from firestore, the component shows nothing the first time but when I click navbar button again it does show the data stored in firestore.

Here is the component file :

```
import * as React from "react";
import Category from "./Category";
import connect from "react-redux/es/connect/connect";
import {getCategories} from "../reducers/actions/categoryAction";

class CategoriesList extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = ({
            categoriesList: [{}]
        })
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.props.getCategories();
        this.setState({categoriesList: this.props.categories});
        this.forceUpdate();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className={'container categories'}>
                <div className={'row center'} onClick={() => this.props.history.push('/addcategories')}>
                    <div className={'col s24 m12'}>
                        <p>Create New Category</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div className={'row'}>
                    <div className={'col s24 m12'}>
                        {/*{() => this.renderCategories()}*/}


                        {this.state.categoriesList && this.state.categoriesList.map(category => {
                            return <Category category={category} key={category.id}/>
                        })}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapDisptachToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        getCategories: () => dispatch(getCategories()),
    }
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        categories: state.category.categories
    }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDisptachToProps)(CategoriesList)
```

And here is the reducer file:

```
 import db from '../firebaseConfig'


const initState = {
    categories: []
};

const categoryReducer = (state=initState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'CREATE_CATEGORY':
            db.collection("Categories").add({
                category: action.category.name
            })
                .then(function(docRef) {
                    db.collection("Categories").get().then((querySnapshot) => {
                        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                            // console.log(`${doc.id} => ${doc.data().category}`);
                            if(doc.id === docRef.id) {
                                state.categories.push({id: doc.id, name: doc.data().category});
                                console.log(state.categories)
                            }
                        });
                    });
                })
                .catch(function(error) {
                    console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
                });
            break;

        case 'GET_CATEGORIES':
            console.log('Getting data from firestore');

            db.collection("Categories").get().then((querySnapshot) => {
                if(state.categories.length !== querySnapshot.size) {
                    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                        state.categories.push({id: doc.id, name: doc.data().category});
                    });
                }
            });
            break;
    }
  return state;
};

export default categoryReducer
```

Is there any way to update the component after fully loading the data? or a way to load all the data in the initalState?

Comment: Did you try to use ComponentDidMount instead of componentWillMount ?

Comment: @LeonardoLobato Yes, I have tried  `componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        if (prevProps.categoriesList.length !== this.categoriesList.length) {
            this.forceUpdate();
        }
    }`

Comment: `getCategories()` is a AJAX request. When you `setState` after that request, the `categories` isn't set yet from the AJAX response.

Comment: @Hoyen so should I use delay?

Comment: componentDidMount not componentDidUpdate... 

and probably what you probably mean was componetWillReceiveProps no componentDidUpdate.

you can get ride of this.forceUpdate() if you use the right lifecycle method you probably don't need this.

try the componentDidMount and if still not work try the componentWillReceiveProps

Comment: @SimpleWebDesigner why aren't you using a Redux action to implement the AJAX calls? 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45513318/perform-ajax-fetch-in-a-redux-reducer

Comment: @Hoyen I don't see a difference between my code and the post...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are few things one needs to understand. First, `this.props.getCategories()` performs an action that is asynchronous in nature and hence in the very next line `this.setState({categoriesList: this.props.categories});`, we wont get the required data.

Second, Storing props to state without any modification is un-necessary and leads to complications. So try to use the props directly without storing it. In case you are modifying the obtained props, make sure you override `getDerivedStateFromProps` apropiately.

Third, Try to use `componentDidMount` to perform such async operations than `componentWillMount`. Refer [when to use componentWillMount instead of componentDidMount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48400029/when-to-use-componentwillmount-instead-of-componentdidmount).

Fourth(**important in your case**), `Reducer` should not contain async operations. Reducer should be a synchronous operation which will return a new state. In your case, you need to fetch the data elsewhere and then `dispatch` within your `db.collection(..).then` **callback**. You can also use [redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk), if you are using too many async operations to get your redux updated.

So @Mis94 answer should work if you follow the fourth point of returning the new state in the reducer rather than mutating the redux directly in the `db().then` `callback`

Comment: Read about Redux reducers here:
https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers
https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/structuring-reducers
As mentioned in the first link:  just remember that the reducer must be pure. Given the same arguments, it should calculate the next state and return it. No surprises. No side effects. No API calls. No mutations. Just a calculation. So you shouldn't be doing API calls or retrieving data inside it according to Redux documentation.

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need to store the component's props in the state object. This is actually considered an [anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40063468/react-component-initialize-state-from-props/47341539#47341539) in react. Instead of doing this, just use your props directly in your render method:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div className={'container categories'}>
            <div className={'row center'} onClick={() => this.props.history.push('/addcategories')}>
                <div className={'col s24 m12'}>
                    <p>Create New Category</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div className={'row'}>
                <div className={'col s24 m12'}>
                    {/*{() => this.renderCategories()}*/}


                    {this.props.categories && this.props.categories.map(category => {
                        return <Category category={category} key={category.id}/>
                    })}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Hence in your `componentWillMount` you only need to initiate your request:

```
componentWillMount() {
    this.props.getCategories();
}
```

You can also do it in `componentDidMount()` lifecycle method.

Now when your request resolves and your categories update in the store (Redux) they will be passed again to your component causing it to update. This will also happen with every update in the categories stored in the store.

Also you don't have to call `forceUpdate` like this unless you have components implementing `shouldComponentUpdate` lifecycle method and you want them to ignore it and do a force update. You can Read about all these lifecycle methods (and you have to if you are using React) [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle).

Comment: Are you sure your request really returns data...did you try console.log(querySnapshot); inside .then()  ?